# Issue with ASP.Net Web Api being available for cross domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created a simple asp.net site and used web api that reads from a database.  It all works and has been tested.  I have now put it on a server for testing.

When I test it now I get:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So

I have installed the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`.

Added the line `config.EnableCors()` to `WebApiConfig Register()` function.

I added the enable cors line on the relevant controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ArenaController : ApiController
{
```

I have re-deployed and restarted the site but still getting the same message, any clues?

Comment: what request are you sending? Is there any pre-flight request being sent?The server must set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to allow cross domain calls.

Comment: sending a simple jquery ajax get request.  Where should I set that response header?

Comment: It should be set on the response header by the server. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Isn't the above EnableCors(origins line covering this?

Comment: **If the server allows the request, it sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The value of this header either matches the Origin header, or is the wildcard value “*”, meaning that any origin is allowed.**. source - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have already used the wildcard * as you can see in the code above, so doesn't explain why I still get the issue